# Android client unable to reach the Python server

Tags: java, android, python-3.x, sockets, android-studio

I am trying to develop an application where an android client sends and receives data from Python server via Socket programming. There are no errors nor any exception crashes but my client is unable to reach the python server as my server is not receiving any connection from any client. I have turned off my windows firewall so that my PC does not block unknown access. I tried referring to similar articles in stack exchange but they all say that they are receiving the connection from the client. Please tell me what is wrong with my code. 
Thank you in advance.
(In my server code if I use my PC's IP address then it shows an error 10049 so I am using the localhost IP)

```
/*Client side code- Android*/
    public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
            ArrayList<String> matches = bundle
                    .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            if(matches.get(0) != null)
            {
                final String text = matches.get(0);
                Thread t = new Thread(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Socket s = new Socket("47.11.229.90",25001);
                            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                            dos.writeUTF(text);

                            //read input stream
                            DataInputStream dis2 = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                            InputStreamReader disR2 = new InputStreamReader(dis2);
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(disR2);//create a BufferReader object for input

                            //print the input to the application screen
                            String replyMsg = br.toString();
                            HashMap<String, String> myHashAlarm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
                            myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "SOME MESSAGE");
                            //String random = (helloMessages[new Random().nextInt(helloMessages.length)]);
                            ts.speak(replyMsg, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashAlarm);
                            pulseView.startPulse();
                            //tvr.setText("Hey");
                            //final TextView receivedMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                            //receivedMsg.setText(br.toString());

                            dis2.close();
                            s.close();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                };
                t.start();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sending data: " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                /*
                if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("Hi") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("Hello") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("Hey") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("Hello Pi") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("Hi Pi") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("Hey Pi"))
                {
                    //new RetriveByteArray().execute("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/master/demo/demo-3.gif");
                    //gif.startAnimation();
                    HashMap<String, String> myHashAlarm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
                    myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "SOME MESSAGE");
                    String random = (helloMessages[new Random().nextInt(helloMessages.length)]);
                    ts.speak(random, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashAlarm);
                    pulseView.startPulse();
                    tvr.setText("Hey");
                }
                else if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("Who are you") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("Introduce Yourself") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("Tell me something about yourself") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("Describe yourself"))
                {
                    //new RetriveByteArray().execute("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/master/demo/demo-3.gif");
                    //gif.startAnimation();
                    HashMap<String, String> myHashAlarm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
                    myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "SOME MESSAGE");
                    String random = (introMessages[new Random().nextInt(introMessages.length)]);
                    ts.speak(random, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashAlarm);
                    pulseView.startPulse();
                    tvr.setText("Hey this is Doctor Pi");

                }
                else if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("I love you")|| text.equalsIgnoreCase("I am in love with your voice") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("Hey Akanksha"))
                {
                    //new RetriveByteArray().execute("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/master/demo/demo-3.gif");
                    //gif.startAnimation();
                    HashMap<String, String> myHashAlarm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
                    myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "SOME MESSAGE");
                    ts.speak("I Love you too", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashAlarm);
                    pulseView.startPulse();
                    tvr.setText("I Love you too");
                } else {
                    //new RetriveByteArray().execute("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/master/demo/demo-3.gif");
                    //gif.startAnimation();
                    HashMap<String, String> myHashAlarm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
                    myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "SOME MESSAGE");
                    String random = (sorryMessages[new Random().nextInt(sorryMessages.length)]);
                    ts.speak(random, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashAlarm);
                    pulseView.startPulse();
                    tvr.setText("Sorry!");
                }*/
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Null string received",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            //for (String result : matches)
            //    text += result;
        }
/*Server side code-Python*/
import sqlite3
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from socket import *

HOST = "127.0.0.1" #local host  IT SHOWS AN ERROR WHEN I USE MY PC's IP ADDRESS  47.11.229.90
PORT = 25001 #open port 18000 for connection
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
print("Hello")
s.listen(1) #how many connections can it receive at one time
connect_device, addr = s.accept() #accept the connection
print("Connected by: ",addr)

while True:
    print("In the loop")
    data = connect_device.recv(1024)  # how many bytes of data will the server receive
    data = data.decode('utf-8')
    print("Received: ", repr(data))

    conn = sqlite3.connect("ciao.db")
    c=conn.cursor()
    #string = "Hey tell me something about dengue"
    #string2 = string.lower()
    string = repr(data)
    string2 = string.lower()
    list_items = word_tokenize(string2)
    print("List items = ",list_items)
    Greetings = ['hi', "hey"]
    c.execute("SELECT Disease_Name FROM ciao")
    data = c.fetchall()
    data2 = []
    for i in data:
        for j in i:
            if j is not None:
                data2.append(j)

    print("data2 = ",data2)
    msg = ""
    print("loop starts")
    for i in list_items:
        print(i)
        print("Data = ",data2)

        if i in data2:
            if 'symptoms' in list_items:
                c.execute("SELECT Symptoms from ciao WHERE Disease_Name = (?)",(i,))
                sym = c.fetchall()
                for j in sym:
                    for k in j:
                        msg += k + " "
            if 'remedial' in list_items:
                c.execute("SELECT Remedial_Measures from ciao WHERE Disease_Name = (?)", (i,))
                rem = c.fetchall()
                for j in rem:
                    for k in j:
                        msg += k + " "
            if 'medicines' in list_items:
                c.execute("SELECT Medicines from ciao WHERE Disease_Name = (?)", (i,))
                rem = c.fetchall()
                for j in rem:
                    for k in j:
                        msg += k + " "
            if 'diagnostic' in list_items:
                c.execute("SELECT Diagnostic_tests from ciao WHERE Disease_Name = (?)", (i,))
                rem = c.fetchall()
                for j in rem:
                    for k in j:
                        msg += k + " "
            if 'hospitals' in list_items:
                c.execute("SELECT Related_Hospitals from ciao WHERE Disease_Name = (?)",(i,))
                rem = c.fetchall()
                for j in rem:
                    for k in j:
                        msg += k + " "
            if not('symptoms' in list_items) and not('remedial' in list_items) and not('medicines' in list_items) and not('diagnostic' in list_items) and not('hospitals' in list_items):
                c.execute("SELECT * from ciao WHERE Disease_Name = (?)",(i,) )
                rem = c.fetchall()
                for j in rem:
                    for k in j:
                        msg += k + " "

        else:
            if i in Greetings:
                if len(list_items) == 1 or len(list_items) == 0:
                    msg = "Hello I am Pi"
    if msg == "":
        msg = "Sorry"
    print(msg)
    connect_device.sendall(msg)
    conn.close()
connect_device.close()
```

Comment: did you add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> to your AndroidManifest.xml. If yes, please provide the stacktrace after you're trying to communicate your server.

Answer (score 0):

My python code was running on Pycharm so I had to run it in administrator mode, and make sure that you surround the bind function with a try and except blocks. Keep changing the port number every time you run the program and I used my PC's IP address as host address by switching off the windows firewall before executing it for the first time. Now it works -

```
/*Client side- Android text to speech's onResult*/
 @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
        ArrayList<String> matches = bundle
                .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        if(matches.get(0) != null)
        {
            final String text = matches.get(0);
            Thread t = new Thread(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Socket s = new Socket("192.168.43.123",9999);
                        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                        dos.writeUTF(text);

                        //read input stream
                        DataInputStream dis2 = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                        InputStreamReader disR2 = new InputStreamReader(dis2);
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(disR2,65536);//create a BufferReader object for input

                        //print the input to the application screen
                        //final String replyMsg = br.toString();
                        final String replyMsg = br.readLine();
                        //String receivedMsg = new String(replyMsg);
                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,replyMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                        HashMap<String, String> myHashAlarm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
                        myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "SOME MESSAGE");
                        //String random = (helloMessages[new Random().nextInt(helloMessages.length)]);
                        ts.speak(replyMsg, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashAlarm);
                        pulseView.startPulse();
                        //tvr.setText("Hey");
                        //final TextView receivedMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                        //receivedMsg.setText(br.toString());

                        dis2.close();
                        s.close();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sending data: " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            /*
            if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("Hi") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("Hello") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("Hey") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("Hello Pi") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("Hi Pi") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("Hey Pi"))
            {
                //new RetriveByteArray().execute("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/master/demo/demo-3.gif");
                //gif.startAnimation();
                HashMap<String, String> myHashAlarm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
                myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "SOME MESSAGE");
                String random = (helloMessages[new Random().nextInt(helloMessages.length)]);
                ts.speak(random, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashAlarm);
                pulseView.startPulse();
                tvr.setText("Hey");
            }
            else if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("Who are you") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("Introduce Yourself") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("Tell me something about yourself") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("Describe yourself"))
            {
                //new RetriveByteArray().execute("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/master/demo/demo-3.gif");
                //gif.startAnimation();
                HashMap<String, String> myHashAlarm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
                myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "SOME MESSAGE");
                String random = (introMessages[new Random().nextInt(introMessages.length)]);
                ts.speak(random, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashAlarm);
                pulseView.startPulse();
                tvr.setText("Hey this is Doctor Pi");

            }
            else if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("I love you")|| text.equalsIgnoreCase("I am in love with your voice") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("Hey Akanksha"))
            {
                //new RetriveByteArray().execute("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/master/demo/demo-3.gif");
                //gif.startAnimation();
                HashMap<String, String> myHashAlarm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
                myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "SOME MESSAGE");
                ts.speak("I Love you too", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashAlarm);
                pulseView.startPulse();
                tvr.setText("I Love you too");
            } else {
                //new RetriveByteArray().execute("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/master/demo/demo-3.gif");
                //gif.startAnimation();
                HashMap<String, String> myHashAlarm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
                myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "SOME MESSAGE");
                String random = (sorryMessages[new Random().nextInt(sorryMessages.length)]);
                ts.speak(random, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashAlarm);
                pulseView.startPulse();
                tvr.setText("Sorry!");
            }*/
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Null string received",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        //for (String result : matches)
        //    text += result;
    }
/*Server side code- Python server*/
import sqlite3
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from socket import *
import sys
import socket

HOST = "192.168.43.123" #local host  IT SHOWS AN ERROR WHEN I USE MY PC's IP ADDRESS  47.11.229.90 127.0.0.1 192.168.43.123
PORT = 9999 #open port 18000 for connection
s = socket.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as e:
    print("Bind error, Error code: ",e.strerror,"Message: ",e.strerror)
    sys.exit(1)
print("Bind successful")
s.listen(10) #how many connections can it receive at one time
print("In the loop")
while True:
    connect_device, addr = s.accept()  # accept the connection
    print("Connected by: ", addr)
    #msg1 = 'Thank you for connecting' + "\r\n"
    #connect_device.send(msg1.encode('ascii'))
    data = connect_device.recv(4096)  # how many bytes of data will the server receive
    data = data.decode('ascii','ignore')
    print("Received: ", repr(data))

    conn = sqlite3.connect("ciao.db")
    c=conn.cursor()
    #string = "Hey tell me something about dengue"
    #string2 = string.lower()
    string = repr(data)
    string2 = string.lower()
    list_items = word_tokenize(string2)
    list_items2 = []
    for st in list_items:
        list_items2.append(st.strip())
    print("List items = ",list_items2)
    Greetings = ['hi', "hey"]
    c.execute("SELECT Disease_Name FROM ciao")
    data = c.fetchall()
    data2 = []
    for i in data:
        for j in i:
            if j is not None:
                data2.append(j)

    print("data2 = ",data2)
    msg = ""
    print("loop starts")
    for i in list_items2:
        print(i)
        print("Data = ",data2)

        if i in data2:
            if 'symptoms' in list_items2:
                c.execute("SELECT Symptoms from ciao WHERE Disease_Name = (?)",(i,))
                sym = c.fetchall()
                for j in sym:
                    for k in j:
                        msg += k + " "
            if 'remedial' in list_items2:
                c.execute("SELECT Remedial_Measures from ciao WHERE Disease_Name = (?)", (i,))
                rem = c.fetchall()
                for j in rem:
                    for k in j:
                        msg += k + " "
            if 'medicines' in list_items2:
                c.execute("SELECT Medicines from ciao WHERE Disease_Name = (?)", (i,))
                rem = c.fetchall()
                for j in rem:
                    for k in j:
                        msg += k + " "
            if 'diagnostic' in list_items2:
                c.execute("SELECT Diagnostic_tests from ciao WHERE Disease_Name = (?)", (i,))
                rem = c.fetchall()
                for j in rem:
                    for k in j:
                        msg += k + " "
            if 'hospitals' in list_items2:
                c.execute("SELECT Related_Hospitals from ciao WHERE Disease_Name = (?)",(i,))
                rem = c.fetchall()
                for j in rem:
                    for k in j:
                        msg += k + " "
            if not('symptoms' in list_items2) and not('remedial' in list_items2) and not('medicines' in list_items2) and not('diagnostic' in list_items2) and not('hospitals' in list_items2):
                c.execute("SELECT * from ciao WHERE Disease_Name = (?)",(i,) )
                rem = c.fetchall()
                for j in rem:
                    for k in j:
                        msg += k + " "

        else:
            if i in Greetings:
                if len(list_items) == 1 or len(list_items) == 0:
                    msg = "Hello I am Pi"
    if msg == "":
        msg = "Sorry"
    print(msg)
    connect_device.sendall(msg.encode('ascii'))
    #connect_device.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
    conn.close()

connect_device.close()
s.close()
```